# Port based bandwidth shaping

Tags: traffic-shaping, qos, bandwidth-control

I have an interent connection with the speed of 4000k bits up and down. I want to do port based traffic shaping on a ubuntu machine, which acts as router. eth0 is the WAN interface. This is how I would like to allocate bandwidth:

- For ports 80 and 443 the bandwidth usage can go upto 90%
- For ports above 1024 upto 65535 the bandwidth usage can go upto 10%
- For remaining ports the bandwidth usage can go upto 40%

The easiest way for achieving the above is using a router with tomato firmware. I have used it and it is very efficient. I want to try if it can be done on a Ubuntu or any GNU/Linux machine. I have googled extensively about the topic and I feel there isn't much information.

Comment: You have port tcp/445 (microsoft-ds) traffic going to the Internet?  Or did you mean 443?

Comment: See this if you haven't seen it already.  http://lartc.org/

Comment: Yes, I meant 443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using tc and iptables. [This article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-traffic-shaping-using-tc-to-control-http-traffic/) by Vivek Gite walks you through doing it for one port.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this blog post below 8 years ago for FreeBSD using DUMMYNET add-on to ipfw.  It was only IP based traffic shaping (not port-based) but I assume by now there's a port to Ubuntu that supports TCP ports as well.  Scroll past all the noob stuff if your a kernel rebuilding master to see how DUMMYNET concepts work and rulesets.

http://www.fishbrains.com/2003/08/25/controlling-bandwidth-for-your-wireless-network-using-freebsd-and-dummynet/